# How to access webcam via Internet Explorer (11)?

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, web, webcam

**Context:** I'm building an offline website (html5, css, js) which i want to call over IE (11). For taking/saving a picture i need to access the webcam.

**Approach:** I read that IE doesn't support the getUserMedia; and the only way is to use flash.

**Question:** Is the only possibility to access the webcam over IE by using flash? If yes, please recommend an example.

I'd appreciate your input.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes IE 11 and below currently doesn't support `getUserMedia` ,but there is a polyfill available on github, which you can find [here](https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js)

It uses flash fallback in case `getUserMedia` is unavailable so you can give it a try.

**Update 1**

There are a few more polyfills available and are listed under

[webrtc4all](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc4all/)  and [Temasys WebRTC](https://temasys.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TWPP/WebRTC+Plugins/) can provides fallback via an NPAPI/ActiveX plugin.

Comment: https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs simple and eas