# Will Windows 10 store applications support getUserMedia()?

Tags: html, windows, windows-10, getusermedia

Will Windows 10 store applications support getUserMedia() ? I'm currently trying to create a Windows 8.1 application with JavaScript and HTML5 and it does not support the function. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access webcam via Internet Explorer (11)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676240/how-to-access-webcam-via-internet-explorer-11)

Comment: Windows 10 used IE11. The dup answers your question.

Comment: So Windows 10 runs on IE11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported in IE but is [Available for preview](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/mediacaptureandstreams?filter=f010000bf&search=UserMedia).

**Update:** It is now supported in Microsoft Edge.

> Provides access to the user's local audio and video input/output devices (getUserMedia API).
>
> Unprefixed version:Microsoft Edge build 10240+