# Option for navigator.GetUserMedia for IE Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I want to open a webcam using JavaScript/jQuery.

I am able to open it in Chrome and Mozilla. But `navigator.GetUserMedia` is not working for the IE browser. Is it possible to do this with IE using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access webcam via Internet Explorer (11)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676240/how-to-access-webcam-via-internet-explorer-11)

Answer (score 2):

Yes IE 11 and below currently doesn't support getUserMedia ,but there is a polyfill available

http://caniuse.com/#search=getuserMedia

This is the only polyfill I can find, and it uses a flash fallback:

https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js

Answer (score 1):

You should use a polyfill. Search for it on the internet

You could try this :

https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js

https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs