# cannot read property ''enumerateDevices' of undefined over http

Tags: c#, asp.net, jasmine, enumerate-devices

I create asp.net web application and copy code from https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/canvas/
and public project to iis  link **http://123.111.1.222/test/camera.aspx** not working  is error

This is the error message
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enumerateDevices'`

code here

```
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(gotDevices).catch(handleError);
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow mam! i do curious, are you using chrome by any chances? there are many ways `mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` may fail, see the [other QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43183514/unable-to-get-property-enumeratedevices-of-undefined-or-null-reference). also pretty please post error message as text..

Comment: @BagusTesa  error message : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enumerateDevices')

Comment: navigator.mediaDevices is exposed to secure contexts only. This means your website needs to be served over HTTPS, not HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be on `https://` or `localhost` for `navigator.mediaDevices` to be available.

For security purposes, accessing `mediaDevices` on `http://` is not allowed. Therefore, you receive an error that it cannot find the fuction `enumerateDevices`, because indeed, `mediaDevices` is undefined.

Solutions, from easy to hard:

- Use `localhost` as your development server.
- Tunnel your local server using a tool such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or [localtunnel](https://theboroer.github.io/localtunnel-www/), which will act as a https to http proxy.
- Upload your app to a server supporting `https`.
- Add SSL certificates to your development server, and access using `https://`.