# access webcam from internet explorer has trouble

Tags: internet-explorer, webcam

I want to access my webcam from internet explorer. Is it possible? In many online webcam tester IE has trouble. I want it in IE. Is there any idea?

Answer (score 0):

We usually use `getUserMedia()` to access webcam, but IE doesn't support this method. You could ues a [polyfill: getUserMedia.js](https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js) for `getUserMedia()` in IE. It uses flash fallback in case `getUserMedia()` is unavailable.

For more information and other polyfills, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676240/how-to-access-webcam-via-internet-explorer-11).