# How can i manage webcam in my web appliction using Internet Explorer without Flash Player?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, flash, webcam

im trying to create an application with **webcam integration**, my app only run on **Internet Explorer** because it manage external device with **activeX**, months ago i implemented *webcamjs* library but it works with Adobe Flash Player which is deprecated and now i can't run any flash component in my application.

is there another way to manage webcam on Internet Explorer without Flash?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access webcam via Internet Explorer (11)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676240/how-to-access-webcam-via-internet-explorer-11)

Answer (score 0):

I try to search but did not get any working example to manage the webcam without using Flash. Some old libraries and APIs are available but they may give inconsistent results with the IE 11 or may not work.

If possible you can try to move to the latest browsers. There you will not have to depend upon Flash.

If you cant move to the latest browsers then you can try to refer to [this document](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2020/09/04/update-adobe-flash-end-support/). Please check **Options for continued support for enterprise customers** point. You can try to contact Adobe for Enterprise customer support, they can provide some options that might help to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML 5, the following link has a nice explanation:

https://www.kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm

---

EDIT: just noticed - you want IE. This is a pity. I would propose rather switch to a state of the art HTML 5 capable browser.